# loading data simultaneosuly

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have multiple dataTables and using ajax to load the dataTables data. I have mapped a managed bean with the dataTables and through ajax update can able to hit the database and get/retrieve the records from database. Issue is few tables may have few records to display and few have more.I want to show the records which ever are available first instead of all table to load.
Please suggest.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked outputPanel's deferred loading in [the PrimeFaces Showcase?](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/outputPanel.xhtml)

Answer (score 2):

In most of the big data applications this scenario is important, especially when you have datatables with a big data to be fetched from the DB, basically it's a way of lazyloading.

*Before answering this question I'de like to point out that using the getters/setters for a logic/fetch is a bad idea, because they're called multiple times during the lifecycle.*

***Steps:***

- Separate the getters logic to another fetching/generating methods.

  ```
  public void fetchSpreadList() {
     //fetch from DB and set spreadList
     setSpreadList(db.findSpreadList());
  }

  public void fetchTransList() throws Exception { 
     //fetch from DB and set TransList    
     setTransList(db.findTransList());
  }

  //getters
  public List<SpreadInformationDTO> getSpreadList() {
     return spreadList;
  }

  public List<TransHistoryDataDTO> getTransList() {      
     return transList;
  }
  ```
- Fetch data using remoteCommand

  ```
   <p:remoteCommand name="fetchSpread"                          
                    actionListener="#{transactionMB.fetchSpreadList}"
                    update=":form1:spreadInfo"
                    onstart="preTableIsLoading(PF('widVarMnmsInfo'))"
                    oncomplete="postTableIsLoading(PF('widVarMnmsInfo'))">
   </p:remoteCommand>

   <p:remoteCommand name="fetchTrans"
                    actionListener="#{transactionMB.fetchTransList}"
                    update=":form2:withdrawInfo"
                    onstart="preTableIsLoading(PF('widVarBrmOrderInfo'))"
                    oncomplete="postTableIsLoading(PF('widVarBrmOrderInfo'))">       
   </p:remoteCommand>
  ```

  Each remoteCommand would fetch the data once the page is loaded, and update the datatable.
     `onstart` and `oncomplete` here are a loading indicators, passing a `widgetVar` to both `preTableIsLoading` and  `postTableIsLoading`.
     Note: if you use PF 3.5 or lower pass the widgetVar without `PF` shortcut.
- `preTableIsLoading` and  `postTableIsLoading` **(javascript)**

  ```
  function preTableIsLoading(widget) {
     widget.jq.find('.ui-datatable-empty-message td').hide();
     widget.jq.find('.ui-datatable-empty-message')
            .append('<span class="tableLoadingSpan" />');
  }

  function postTableIsLoading(widget) {
     widget.jq.find('.ui-datatable-empty-message td').show();
     widget.jq.find('.ui-datatable-empty-message span').remove();
  }
  ```

  when the fetch starts, hide the empty message and append to it a loading gif, when the fetch is complete show the empty message (if the datatable is empty) and remove the loading gif indicator.
- Loading gif indicator **(CSS)**

  ```
  .tableLoadingSpan {
     background:
         url("#{resource['/images/loaderTables.gif']}");
     display: block;
     height: 40px;
     margin-top: 20px;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  ```

  [image: loaderTables.gif]

Last thing consider using [lazy loading](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml) in your tables.

**Edit:**

In order to prevent the `undefined` jQuery object error in the javascript, remove `autoRun` from the remoteCommands (which I already removed from this answer) and call the remoteCommands in the `$(document).ready()` that way you make sure the widgetVar is ready to be used.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //calling remoteCommands
   fetchSpread();
   fetchTrans();
})
```

Comment: +1 appreciate your effort,i will be doing the way you mentioned now, do i need to implement lazy loading functionality as you mentioned in your last line, please suggest.@Hatem Alimam.

Comment: I have a "personal" rule: if my datatable or any query would load more than 100 records then a lazy loading is important, this way my query would load max 10 records (or if the user chose another amount) per page. and PrimeFaces is good at it so far, although you need to adjust your JPA QL or criteria quires to it.

Comment: Ok, so from my side no need to implement Lazy loading rite, if i want i can do it at database side. @Hatem Alimam

Comment: It is a two part implementation front-end and back-end, please see the link into the [showcase of lazy loading](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml)

Comment: But again, the answer would solve the issue where the page is stuck till the records are fetched.. here at least the user would see the full page is loaded and an indicator that "we're fetching your data"

Comment: I can see the following error on browser console, Cannot read property 'jq' of undefined, so i'm not getting the expected output.What is 'jq' do i need to place any extra code. Thanks, @Hatem Alimam

Comment: Which PrimeFaces version are you using ?

Comment: I have edited the answer.. again make sure your logic is not in the getters.

Comment: This won't boost up the performance, it's a way to show the page first then load the data, to boost up the performance lazy loading would be the answer, again if you have big dataset

Comment: First make sure that your datatables have the exact widgetVar names, if they're the same try this for every call `setTimeout(fetchSpread, 2000);` `setTimeout(fetchTrans, 2000);` ... if you still have a problem locating the widgetVars the I suspect you have some conflict in jQuery.

Comment: Well I think we reached a died end, to me this approach is the very basic between PrimeFaces and jQuery! anyway you may remove the onstart and oncomplete but I think it would be ugly from a user prospective!

Comment: @HatemAlimam, do i need to add "ui-datatable-empty-message" in my transaction.xhtml page to solve " TypeError: widget is undefined "

Comment: Try to pass the widgetVar without PF shortcut