# Display message to show users

Tags: ajax, jsf

I want to display message or image when loading the data. 
Please suggest.

Comment: Maybe you can find inspiration here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740990/loading-data-simultaneosuly

Comment: This is a terrible question

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<p:ajaxStatus>
```

Here is an example which shows a dialog as long as the ajax-request is loading. You can trigger the ajax-event with

```
<p:ajax event="tabChange">
```

Example that shows a .gif inside of a dialog:

```
<p:ajaxStatus styleClass="ajaxLoader" onstart="blockUI.show();" oncomplete="blockUI.hide();">  
</p:ajaxStatus>

<p:dialog id="ajaxDialog" widgetVar="blockUI" modal="true">
   <h:graphicImage value="/path/ajax-loader.gif" />
</p:dialog>
```